# Memory Limits (UM, UME, UMEH)

Tags: linux, memory, defragmentation

I have a system where multiple servers are all set up in the same way with the same specs.  These are dedicated to processing recordings of online meetings, as well as transferring audio and video via WebRTC (Jitsi is the open source software that runs behind the scenes).

Recently one of them has been running into a memory problem and gives...

`Out of memory: Killed process 3137519 (ffmpeg) total-vm:17368036kB, anon-rss:15560988kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:8104kB, UID:99`

Before that, there's a bunch of other code from the logs that is related to memory.

So, I've run `echo m > /proc/sysrq-trigger` with idea that there could be memory fragmentation or something on that one server (JVB7).  I also ran this on the other servers (JVB1, JVB2, etc.) to compare the results, which are...

JVB 1

```
Dec 21 09:58:51 jvb1 kernel: [21431720.705523] Node 0 DMA: 1*4kB (U) 0*8kB 0*16kB 1*32kB (U) 2*64kB (U) 1*128kB (U) 1*256kB (U) 0*512kB 1*1024kB (U) 2*2048kB (UM) 2*4096kB (M) = 13860kB 
Dec 21 09:58:51 jvb1 kernel: [21431720.705534] Node 0 DMA32: 139*4kB (UM) 253*8kB (UM) 223*16kB (UME) 193*32kB (UME) 158*64kB (UME) 152*128kB (UME) 127*256kB (UME) 107*512kB (UME) 96*1024kB (UME) 81*2048kB (ME) 650*4096kB (ME) = 3055780kB 
Dec 21 09:58:51 jvb1 kernel: [21431720.705673] Node 0 Normal: 24006*4kB (UMEH) 35801*8kB (UMEH) 15353*16kB (UMEH) 1318*32kB (UMEH) 4912*64kB (UMEH) 4861*128kB (UME) 2867*256kB (UME) 1776*512kB (UME) 871*1024kB (UM) 534*2048kB (M) 1446*4096kB (M) = 11158448kB
```

JVB 2

```
Dec 21 09:58:56 jvb2 kernel: [29874916.050571] Node 0 DMA: 0*4kB 0*8kB 0*16kB 0*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 1*1024kB (U) 2*2048kB (UM) 2*4096kB (M) = 13312kB
Dec 21 09:58:56 jvb2 kernel: [29874916.052495] Node 0 DMA32: 5*4kB (UM) 5*8kB (M) 7*16kB (M) 8*32kB (M) 5*64kB (M) 5*128kB (M) 8*256kB (UM) 6*512kB (UM) 8*1024kB (UM) 4*2048kB (UM) 732*4096kB (M) = 3021164kB
Dec 21 09:58:56 jvb2 kernel: [29874916.054570] Node 0 Normal: 1149*4kB (UME) 1722*8kB (UME) 14022*16kB (UME) 12255*32kB (UME) 6711*64kB (UME) 2131*128kB (UME) 523*256kB (UME) 286*512kB (UME) 190*1024kB (UME) 181*2048kB (UME) 2274*4096kB (ME) = 11497028kB
```

JVB 3

```
Dec 21 09:59:00 jvb3 kernel: [22612915.555862] Node 0 DMA: 0*4kB 0*8kB 0*16kB 0*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 1*1024kB (U) 2*2048kB (UM) 2*4096kB (M) = 13312kB
Dec 21 09:59:00 jvb3 kernel: [22612915.555875] Node 0 DMA32: 2*4kB (UM) 2*8kB (M) 1*16kB (M) 3*32kB (M) 1*64kB (M) 2*128kB (M) 3*256kB (UM) 2*512kB (UM) 3*1024kB (UM) 4*2048kB (UM) 744*4096kB (M) = 3060936kB
Dec 21 09:59:00 jvb3 kernel: [22612915.555891] Node 0 Normal: 14878*4kB (UME) 47825*8kB (UME) 17935*16kB (UME) 4445*32kB (UME) 4506*64kB (UME) 1600*128kB (UME) 775*256kB (UME) 508*512kB (UME) 206*1024kB (UME) 121*2048kB (UME) 2156*4096kB (UME) = 11112720kB
```

JVB 4

```
Dec 21 09:59:04 jvb4 kernel: [11059853.927444] Node 0 DMA: 0*4kB 0*8kB 0*16kB 0*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 1*1024kB (U) 2*2048kB (UM) 2*4096kB (M) = 13312kB
Dec 21 09:59:04 jvb4 kernel: [11059853.929533] Node 0 DMA32: 0*4kB 3*8kB (UM) 1*16kB (M) 2*32kB (M) 1*64kB (M) 2*128kB (M) 2*256kB (M) 2*512kB (UM) 3*1024kB (UM) 2*2048kB (UM) 744*4096kB (M) = 3056552kB
Dec 21 09:59:04 jvb4 kernel: [11059853.932025] Node 0 Normal: 27634*4kB (UME) 49583*8kB (UME) 21740*16kB (UME) 8251*32kB (UME) 5874*64kB (UME) 1256*128kB (UME) 450*256kB (UME) 342*512kB (UME) 212*1024kB (UME) 120*2048kB (UME) 2201*4096kB (UME) = 11424224kB
```

JVB 5

```
Dec 21 09:59:07 jvb5 kernel: [22612851.524974] Node 0 DMA: 0*4kB 0*8kB 0*16kB 0*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 1*1024kB (U) 2*2048kB (UM) 2*4096kB (M) = 13312kB
Dec 21 09:59:07 jvb5 kernel: [22612851.524986] Node 0 DMA32: 171*4kB (UM) 85*8kB (UM) 59*16kB (UM) 41*32kB (UM) 37*64kB (UM) 27*128kB (UM) 29*256kB (M) 27*512kB (M) 28*1024kB (M) 18*2048kB (UM) 714*4096kB (ME) = 3020772kB
Dec 21 09:59:07 jvb5 kernel: [22612851.525001] Node 0 Normal: 12900*4kB (UME) 37805*8kB (UME) 8036*16kB (UME) 9867*32kB (UME) 10935*64kB (UME) 6135*128kB (UME) 2847*256kB (UME) 1663*512kB (UME) 866*1024kB (UME) 465*2048kB (M) 1143*4096kB (M) = 10384600kB
```

JVB 6

```
Dec 21 09:59:11 jvb6 kernel: [22612874.155804] Node 0 DMA: 0*4kB 0*8kB 0*16kB 0*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 1*1024kB (U) 2*2048kB (UM) 2*4096kB (M) = 13312kB
Dec 21 09:59:11 jvb6 kernel: [22612874.155825] Node 0 DMA32: 1*4kB (U) 2*8kB (M) 1*16kB (M) 2*32kB (M) 1*64kB (M) 2*128kB (M) 3*256kB (UM) 2*512kB (UM) 3*1024kB (UM) 2*2048kB (UM) 744*4096kB (M) = 3056804kB
Dec 21 09:59:11 jvb6 kernel: [22612874.155836] Node 0 Normal: 37803*4kB (UME) 46624*8kB (UME) 12425*16kB (UME) 3294*32kB (UME) 793*64kB (UME) 199*128kB (UME) 111*256kB (UME) 119*512kB (UME) 136*1024kB (UME) 114*2048kB (UME) 2273*4096kB (ME) = 10676924kB
```

**JVB 7 [This is the problem server]**

```
Dec 21 09:54:17 jvb7 kernel: [22612487.261867] Node 0 DMA: 0*4kB 0*8kB 0*16kB 0*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 1*1024kB (U) 2*2048kB (UM) 2*4096kB (M) = 13312kB
Dec 21 09:54:17 jvb7 kernel: [22612487.261881] Node 0 DMA32: 886*4kB (UME) 804*8kB (UME) 691*16kB (UME) 605*32kB (UME) 436*64kB (UME) 361*128kB (UME) 286*256kB (UME) 255*512kB (UME) 219*1024kB (UME) 174*2048kB (UM) 525*4096kB (UME) = 3049288kB
Dec 21 09:54:17 jvb7 kernel: [22612487.262165] Node 0 Normal: 4981*4kB (UMEH) 4319*8kB (UMEH) 3318*16kB (UMEH) 2902*32kB (UMEH) 2284*64kB (UMEH) 1792*128kB (UMEH) 1435*256kB (UMEH) 1198*512kB (UME) 970*1024kB (UMH) 871*2048kB (M) 1984*4096kB (M) = 12460268kB**
```

JVB 8

```
Dec 21 09:59:19 jvb8 kernel: [3103949.381251] Node 0 DMA: 0*4kB 0*8kB 0*16kB 0*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 1*1024kB (U) 2*2048kB (UM) 2*4096kB (M) = 13312kB
Dec 21 09:59:19 jvb8 kernel: [3103949.381263] Node 0 DMA32: 4*4kB (UM) 1*8kB (M) 2*16kB (M) 3*32kB (M) 2*64kB (M) 3*128kB (M) 4*256kB (UM) 2*512kB (UM) 5*1024kB (UM) 3*2048kB (UM) 743*4096kB (M) = 3057304kB
Dec 21 09:59:19 jvb8 kernel: [3103949.381278] Node 0 Normal: 840*4kB (UME) 583*8kB (UME) 8086*16kB (UME) 12545*32kB (UME) 5260*64kB (UME) 1419*128kB (UME) 385*256kB (UME) 187*512kB (UME) 87*1024kB (UME) 80*2048kB (ME) 2464*4096kB (ME) = 11596888kB
```

JVB 9

```
Dec 21 09:59:14 jvb9 kernel: [12093584.127383] Node 0 DMA: 0*4kB 0*8kB 0*16kB 0*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 1*1024kB (U) 2*2048kB (UM) 2*4096kB (M) = 13312kB
Dec 21 09:59:14 jvb9 kernel: [12093584.127392] Node 0 DMA32: 0*4kB 3*8kB (UM) 1*16kB (M) 2*32kB (M) 1*64kB (M) 2*128kB (M) 2*256kB (M) 2*512kB (UM) 3*1024kB (UM) 2*2048kB (UM) 744*4096kB (M) = 3056552kB
Dec 21 09:59:14 jvb9 kernel: [12093584.127404] Node 0 Normal: 31984*4kB (UME) 45537*8kB (UME) 10523*16kB (UME) 3283*32kB (UME) 4207*64kB (UME) 2326*128kB (UME) 875*256kB (UME) 325*512kB (UME) 81*1024kB (UME) 46*2048kB (UME) 2197*4096kB (ME) = 10899096kB
```

I have near zero skills in this area, so I don't really know what I'm looking at.  The one way that JVB7 looks different to me though is that for `Node 0 Normal` there are `UMEH` designations (and none of the other servers have that) and that only one other server has a `UME` designation for `Node 0 DMA32`.

Again, I don't know what this all means, but are the designations in JVB7 an indicator of a memory leak, or fragmentation that can be shored up?